# how to store columns values in array in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am writing code in asp.net. I have a column named c_name in database. I want to store all my columns values in an array. Here is my incomplete code. I am confused what to do here.

```
String str = "select c_name from contacts where user_id = " + user_id + "";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, dbConnection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

while (mdr.Read())
{

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code:

```
   String str = "select c_name from contacts where user_id = " + user_id + "";
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, dbConnection);
   MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

   List<string> list = new List<string>();
   while (mdr.Read())
   {
        list.Add(mdr.GetString(0));
   }

   string[] strMyArray = list.ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: what is `reader`? Please add some more details to fully describe what you are doing

Comment: Also I suspect ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't want to be there and has been copied in by the OP by accident

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of your your problems is this line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You're actually executing cmd twice, once with this line and once again when you create your reader. I've also added a little code to copy the result into an element in a list. Try the following:

```
string str = "select c_name from contacts where user_id = " + user_id + "";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, dbConnection);

MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

// create a list to hold the results in
List<string> results = new List<string>();
while (mdr.Read())
{
  // for each row read a string and add it in
  results.Add(mdr.GetString(0));
}
```

You've asked for an array - I've used a list because it's easier. If you REALLY want an array then just call:

```
var theArray = results.ToArray();
```

I would also suggest throwing in some using blocks around the connection, command and reader.